# How to delete entire rows that have the same value in B column

Tags: excel, vba

I was just wondering how you would go about to delete an entire row IF 2 rows have the same value in the B column. For example.

```
|   A   |    B    |
   keep    20222
  delete   123456
   keep    20223
  delete   123456
```

Comment: see this link: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-list-in-excel-HA001034626.aspx

Comment: This wouldnt help as I'm working with Excel 97. (Work doesn't want to upgrade)

Comment: This sort of thing is easy to do without VBA. Can you provide more details of what your process is and what you need to accomplish, and with what frequency?

Comment: We load an excel sheet from a website, and were not sure if it has duplicates in it. The numbers are going to be work orders we have and we need to delete the duplicate work orders. We're saving the ones that have to be dealt with other groups, and when we load a new excel sheet, we paste the ones that are not completed yet, and we want to delete the ones they are matches with. The only thing were looking at is the information in the "B" column and we want to delete the entire row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, rDel As Range
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rDel = Nothing
    For i = 1 To N
        v = Cells(i, "B").Value
        If wf.CountIf(Range("B:B"), v) > 1 Then
            If rDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rDel = Cells(i, "B")
            Else
                Set rDel = Union(rDel, Cells(i, "B"))
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    If rDel Is Nothing Then
    Else
        rDel.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have data from A1

this code will remove duplicates

```
Sub Macro1()
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo ' if you have header change xlno to xlyes
End Sub
```